# Django Forms - instance it does not work as expected

Tags: django, django-forms

I am following a tutorial and I want to create an edit button for my input but when I click the edit button it returns the form but empty:

**forms.py**

```
class RecordingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recording
        fields = ['component', 'group', 'failure', 'degree_of_failure']
```

**views.py**

```
def edit_recording(request,slug, recording_id):
    recording = get_object_or_404(Recording, pk=recording_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RecordingForm(request.POST, instance=recording)
        if form.is_valid():
            recording = form.save(commit=False)
            recording.save()
            return redirect('data:detail')
    else:
        form = RecordingForm(instance=recording)
    template = 'data/create_recording.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

[the form is empty :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzmfg.jpg)

Comment: Please show your template.

Comment: Make sure recording object contains values by applying breakpoint.

Comment: Also show the template/view that contains "the edit button" you refer to. That screenshot is showing validation errors, which you shouldn't get on GET; this implies you are probably sending a POST to this view to display the initial form.

Comment: Daniel Roseman you are correct! But now I get NoReverseMatch

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

1. Daniel Roseman is correct about GET
2. And I changed these two in order to fix the NoReverseMatch

   plant = get_object_or_404(Plant, slug=slug)

   return redirect('data:detail', slug=plant.slug)